# Get objects that have multiple associated contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 4 models: `Person`, `School`, `Home`, `Office`.

They all have the attributes `id` and `name`

My main model is **person.rb**:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :school, join_table: :school_persons
  has_and_belongs_to_many :home, join_table: :home_persons
  has_and_belongs_to_many :office, join_table: :office_persons
end
```

I want to find all persons that have at least 10 associated contents.

I tried joining it with one model, but I want the content that has at least 10 associated content from *all* the models.

```
person.find_by_sql("
  SELECT person.* 
    FROM persons 
    INNER JOIN office_persons ON persons.id = office_persons.person_id     
    GROUP BY persons.id
    HAVING COUNT(office_persons.art_id) = 10
").count
```

How should I approach this?

Comment: I cleaned up your post... please take the time to review the edit, your post was a complete mess before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're several ways:

- You can employ a `counter_cache`-like column for count (but you'll have to add callbacks to all the related models to update it on create/delete as original counter_cache does)
- Just use separate counter caches for each relation (as of rails 4 counter caches should work on HABTM relations) and select by sum of these
- Heavy sql subqueries (usually not recomended, unless it is a one-off task or you have little data and thus no performance problems)

Query like:

```
 SELECT persons.* FROM persons
 WHERE ((select count(*) from office_persons where person_id=persons.id) + 
        (select count(*) from home_persons where person_id=persons.id)+
        (select count(*) from school_persons where person_id=persons.id)) >= 10
```

- Refactor to `has_many through:...` with single join table and flag for `home`/`office`/etc thus have single counter cache and ability to just